# My CSS layout is not working the way it should

Tags: css, layout

Ok so I have my web page (http://jsfiddle.net/HVGBf/) but it's not working the way I would like it to be working.

As you see on a small browser the Logos text is jumping down because of the line-height.
I'd like the Project Name to be abreast if possible, else i'd like it to be among each other but how can I accomplish that?

Html:

```
<body class="home">    
    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="logo">
            <span>Project name</span>
        </div><!-- endLogo -->

        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li> 
                <li><a href="">Over ons</a></li> 
                <li><a href="">Projecten</a></li> 
                <li><a href="">Vrienden</a></li> 
                <li><a href="">Doneren</a></li> 
                <li><a href="">Contact</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </div><!-- endMenu -->

    </div>
</body>
</html>​
```

Css:

```
 /* Eric Meyer's Reset CSS v2.0 - http://cssreset.com */
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline;margin:0;padding:0}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}body{line-height:1}ol,ul{list-style:none}blockquote,q{quotes:none}blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:none}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}

html, body { font-family: "helvetica", arial; margin: 0; padding: 0; height:100%;}

#wrapper {
    min-width: 800px;
}

.home #logo { 
    background: #00B65F; 
    width: 22%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 1% 0 2%; 
    text-align: right;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px; 
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px; 

    line-height: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    font-size: 220%;
}
.home #logo span {
    font-color: #000;
}
.home #menu {
    background-color: #000; 
    float: right; 
    background-repeat: repeat; 
    padding: 56px 5% 56px 1%; 
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px ;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px; 
    margin-left: 6%;
    width: 63%;
    height: 70px;
}


#menu ul { 
    float: left; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    width: 100%;

}
#menu li { 
    float: left; 
    list-style-type: none;  
}
#menu a { 
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none; 

    font-size: 150%;
    color: #fff; 
    padding: 0.4em 0.7em 0.4em 0.7em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: block;
}

#menu a:hover, #menu .active { background-color: #00B65F; }
​
```

Comment: Sorry for being rude (not my intention), but such a question sounds like "do it for me." (I can't see no `code` and `?` question marks.) Most likely to be closed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "abreast" and "among each other". Could you elaborate?

Comment: The Logo "Project Name" i'd like it to be shown side by side. If that's not possible because the width of the #logo is too small and the width of the "Project Name" is bigger than the #logo width the show it like this "Project (line-break) Name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the words "Project" and "Name" to be on one line, then this should do the trick:

```
#logo span { white-space: nowrap; }
```

The text might extend outside of `#logo` due to how you've sized it (by percentage), so to fix that you could also add a minimum width like so:

```
#logo { min-width: 200px; }
```

**Edit:** I noticed you also have `margin-left` set to `6%`. I would recommend using a constant value like `20px`. Also, here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HVGBf/1/) with the recommendations I've mentioned.

Comment: Ok, so I've changed the #logo span and the #logo with what you said, but then when I make my browser smaller the #menu div is going to appear below the #logo div. I can't get it to be on one line?

Comment: @Peacy that is part of the reason why I recommended using constant margins instead of percentages. If you inspect the layout using your browser's developer tools, you'll see that the margins on `#menu` are pushing it to the next row because it takes up too much space. We can't have the logo and menu in one row because there is not enough space to fit it. By setting a smaller (or even better, constant) margin, we can avoid this problem.

Comment: @Peacy another option is to use `position: relative` or `position: absolute` so that they no longer take up the same "space" in the layout. However, the logo and menu may then start to overlap if the browser width gets too short. Yet another option would be to set `min-width: 1000px` on `.home`, which would prevent the page from getting small enough for the menu to be pushed onto a second row.

Comment: ok so I changed the "Project name" to "Stichting Kalpitiya" and set the #logo min-width: 270px; and the .home to width: 960px; but the Menu is going to another row again. I wouldn't go further then 960px because I have to make the webpage also available for small screens.
Edit:  It goes to another row when the width of the browser is 1040+

Comment: @Peacy have you tried changing the `margin-left` of `.home #menu` to something like `20px`? This should allow you to set a lower `min-width`. I would generally not recommend using percentages with margins and padding.